# Query Azure VM platform metrics using REST API

Tags: azure, api, rest, metrics, monitor

I am trying to retrieve default platform-level Azure VM metric values using Azure Monitor REST API, in this case the "Percentage CPU" metric.

```
    $interval = "PT1M"
    $metricnamespace = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
    $metricnames = "Percentage CPU"
    $aggregation = "Average"
    $Uri = "https://management.azure.com/$resourceURI/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?interval=$interval&metricnames=$metricnames&aggregation=$aggregation&api-version=2018-01-01&metricnamespace=$metricnamespace"
    $Response = Invoke-RestMethod $Uri -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json"
```

But when I try to fetch the metric values, I get no data and an empty timeseries object (also with a different timespan):

```
    "cost":  0,
    "timespan":  "2020-07-29T07:34:46Z/2020-07-29T08:34:46Z",
    "interval":  "PT1M",
    "value":  [
                  {
                      "id":  "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/testpatchingVM/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testpatchingVM/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/Percentage CPU",
                      "type":  "Microsoft.Insights/metrics",
                      "name":  "@{value=Percentage CPU; localizedValue=Percentage CPU}",
                      "displayDescription":  "The percentage of allocated compute units that are currently in use by the Virtual Machine(s)",
                      "unit":  "Percent",
                      "timeseries":  "",
                      "errorCode":  "Success"
                  }
              ],
    "namespace":  "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
    "resourceregion":  "westeurope"
```

> 

```
timeStamp           
---------           
2020-07-29T07:43:00Z
2020-07-29T07:44:00Z
2020-07-29T07:45:00Z
2020-07-29T07:46:00Z
2020-07-29T07:47:00Z
2020-07-29T07:48:00Z
2020-07-29T07:49:00Z
2020-07-29T07:50:00Z
2020-07-29T07:51:00Z
2020-07-29T07:52:00Z
2020-07-29T07:53:00Z
2020-07-29T07:54:00Z
2020-07-29T07:55:00Z
2020-07-29T07:56:00Z
2020-07-29T07:57:00Z
2020-07-29T07:58:00Z
2020-07-29T07:59:00Z
2020-07-29T08:00:00Z
2020-07-29T08:01:00Z
2020-07-29T08:02:00Z
2020-07-29T08:03:00Z
2020-07-29T08:04:00Z
2020-07-29T08:05:00Z
2020-07-29T08:06:00Z
2020-07-29T08:07:00Z
2020-07-29T08:08:00Z
2020-07-29T08:09:00Z
2020-07-29T08:10:00Z
2020-07-29T08:11:00Z
2020-07-29T08:12:00Z
...
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: It seems that in the timespan 2020-07-29T07:34:46Z/2020-07-29T08:34:46Z, your vm has been stopped.

Comment: No, the VM was running during that time frame.

Comment: I see the metric values in the Azure portal, but not when using the REST API.

Comment: Please try the rest API vai the [explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list#code-try-0)

Comment: @Jim Xu Problem solved. Apparently there is some delay on showing metric values when using REST API. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since the issue has been resolved, could you please post your answer?